# Table row with two lines of text beside an image

Tags: tables, graphics

I'm trying to replicate this table I made in MS Word, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to accomplish this.

[image: Example]

I'd like to specify all dimensions, such as image dimensions (height=1cm, width depends on aspect ratio), image padding (left=1mm, right=2mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm), and row height (1.2cm) and width (10cm).

I have looked through a lot of StackExchange questions. I've managed two lines of text in a cell with `makecell` and I've managed to wrap text around an image with `wrapfig`, but doing both *inside* a table is proving very difficult. I'm not an experienced LaTeX user. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

As for code: I only have a few lines where I tried several different partial solutions:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[paperwidth=125mm, paperheight=190mm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, inner=2cm, outer=1cm, headheight=0mm, headsep=0mm, marginparwidth=0mm, marginparsep=0mm, footskip=0mm]{geometry}
\special{papersize=125mm,190mm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{cb}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

%\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{environ}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array

\usepackage{wrapfig}

%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

%\begin{table}[h!]
%   \centering
%   \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
%       \hline
%       teste & teste & teste \\ \hline
%       \includegraphics[width=10cm]{../ScriptMapa/exp/pt1.png}
%       &
%       %\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
%       teste
%       %\end{minipage}
%       & 
%       %\begin{minipage}{5cm}
%   teste
%       %\end{minipage}
%       \\ \hline
%   \end{tabular}
%\end{table}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    \makecell[{{p{3cm}}}]{teste \\ teste}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing us with the code you already have (MWE).

Comment: How can you have a width of 10 cm, an image with a width depending on aspect ratio and a predefined padding?

Comment: @Bernard from left to right: 1mm padding, image with variable width, 2mm padding, text, blank space to make the total of 10cm.

Comment: @TeXnician I have edited the question with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can easily get what you need with `tikz`, but with a width of 10cm the gray line goes beyond the right page margin, as you can see with `showframe` package.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[paperwidth=125mm, paperheight=190mm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, inner=2cm, outer=1cm, headheight=0mm, headsep=0mm, marginparwidth=0mm, marginparsep=0mm, footskip=0mm]{geometry}
\special{papersize=125mm,190mm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[minimum height=1.2cm, minimum width=10cm, fill=gray!30, inner sep=0] 
                (A) at (0,0) {};% a width of 10cm goes beyond page margin
        \node[inner sep=0, right=1mm of A.west] (B) {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{FlagPortugal}};
        \node[inner sep=0, right=2mm of B.east, text width=7cm] {{\large Line one} \\ Line two};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's (almost) perfect, I will be able to tweak it to my needs. Thanks a lot!